# TypeError: Expected the `options.agent` properties to be `http`, `https` or `http2`, got `options`

Tags: node.js, proxy, node.js-got

I am trying to set a proxy in my Node.js code. I am using the GOT library of npm to make an API request through my local system.

The code that I am trying to execute:

```js
var tunnelingAgent = tunnel.httpsOverHttps({
  proxy: {
    host: 'rb-proxy-de.abc.com',
    port: 8080,
    proxyAuth : 'username:password',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Node'
    }
  }
});

got({
  'url':'https://services.odata.org/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products',
  'method': "GET",
  'responseType': 'json'
},{agent : tunnelingAgent}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err.stack)
})
```

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Expected the `options.agent` properties to be `http`, `https` or `http2`, got `options`
    at normalizeArguments (C:\Users\hck2kor\Documents\node practice\proxy\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:611:27)
    at normalizeArguments (C:\Users\hck2kor\Documents\node practice\proxy\node_modules\got\dist\source\as-promise\core.js:34:31)
    at got (C:\Users\hck2kor\Documents\node practice\proxy\node_modules\got\dist\source\create.js:104:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hck2kor\Documents\node practice\proxy\proxycode.js:54:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

How do I fix this error?
How do I set proxy while using the GOT library of node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```js
got(..., {
    agent: tunnel.httpsOverHttps(...)
});
```

To:

```js
got(..., {
    agent: {
        https: tunnel.httpsOverHttps(...)
    }
});
```

References:

- [Readme - `agent` object](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#agent)
- [Readme - Proxies](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#proxies)
- [Pull request - readme - change of example code](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/pull/1203/files#diff-0730bb7c2e8f9ea2438b52e419dd86c9R1434-R1442)